# How to get search value of leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

```
      L.control.scale({ position: 'bottomleft' }).addTo(leafletMap);
    var searchcontroloption={position: 'topleft'};
     L.Control.geocoder(searchcontroloption)
    .on('markgeocode', function(e) {

             })
.addTo(leafletMap);
```

I want to get search value, which user has typed in leaflet search box
is there anyway to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to get what has been typed by the user. On latest version of L.Control.geocoder, the search `<input>` is located in a `<div>` which has 'leaflet-control-geocoder-form' class. With JQuery :

```
L.Control.geocoder(searchcontroloption).on('markgeocode', function(e) {
    var searchTxt = $('div.leaflet-control-geocoder-form input').val();
});
```

Without JQuery :

```
L.Control.geocoder(searchcontroloption).on('markgeocode', function(e) {
    var searchTxt = document.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-control-geocoder-form")[0]
                   .childNodes[0].value;
});
```